# Unable to pass multiple arguments to PL/SQL Cursor

Tags: plsql

I have a following requirement where I need to pass a set of values to the Cursor.

Example:

Cursor definition is

```
CURSOR cur_fetch_records (
    v_shop_name VARCHAR2
) IS SELECT
    customer_name 
    from w_customer_d where 
    shipping_location IN v_shop_name;
```

Where the value of the cursor parameter v_shop_name is something like ('A', 'B', 'C')

Now, the problem arises when I OPEN the cursor and pass that argument.

The cursor is opened as :

```
OPEN cur_fetch_records('A', 'B', 'C');
```

Compiler treats it as multiple parameters (as the values are separated by a comma).
I have looked everywhere but I could not figure out a way to pass parameter which is used in a WHERE IN clause of the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass in an argument that is a single string, you can't expect the SQL engine to interpret it as a list. Instead you should pass in an array. Here's an example using the typical employees table:

```
CREATE TYPE names_t IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (100)
/

DECLARE
   CURSOR cur_fetch_records (v_shop_names names_t)
   IS
      SELECT last_name
        FROM hr.employees
       WHERE last_name IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (v_shop_names));

   l_names   names_t := names_t ('King', 'Ande', 'Bell');
   l_name    hr.employees.last_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
   OPEN cur_fetch_records (l_names);

   FETCH cur_fetch_records INTO l_name;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_name);

   CLOSE cur_fetch_records;
END;
/
```

and here's a [link to a LiveSQL script](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_J228LJ2QCEAUJE1J393WYBGF3.html) so you can easily play around with this.